# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: you must pass Joi as an argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose-schema, joi, objectid

How do I solve this Joi problem(Using express, joi@17.4.2,joi-objectid@2.0.0, ,mongoose) I am trying to link two mongoose schemas using ref as

```
{
...
   enroledcourses: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "courses"
    }]
}
```

joi validation

```
...    
enroledcourses: Joi.array().items(Joi.ObjectId()).required()
```

the course collection is fine
i have imported it at index.js as below

```
const Joi = require("joi")
Joi.objectId = require("joi-objectid")(Joi);
```

but i end up getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iST2.png)

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: you must pass Joi as an argument
> at joiObjectId (D:\Programing projects\2021\ikodeafrika\ikodeafrikabackend\node_modules\joi-objectid\index.js:6:3)
> at Object. (D:\Programing projects\2021\ikodeafrika\ikodeafrikabackend\index.js:2:39)

index.js:2:39 being the joi.objectId import above plus  i'm getting this when i hover over the joi.objectId import statement

> Property 'objectId' may not exist on type 'Root'. Did you mean 'object'?ts(2568)
> index.d.ts(1998, 9): 'object' is declared here.
> any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `joi-objectid@2.0.0` is not compatible with `joi@17.4.2`.

**Fix:**
Upgrade `joi-objectid` to `v4.0.2`

About the Typescript error (Property 'objectId' may not exist on type 'Root'), you need to augment the type of `Joi` to add the `objectId` property. This can be done by creating a declaration file:

```
// src/types/joi.d.ts
import { Schema } from "joi";

declare module "joi" {
  interface Root {
    objectId(): Schema;
  }
}
```